# How should I deal with a "trick question"?

Tags: support, flags, asking-questions, rules

Yesterday I saw this question: [SELECT max value with each group without summing - SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74756719/select-max-value-with-each-group-without-summing-sql) and after examining the code I voted to be closed as:

> Not reproducible or was caused by a typo

and also left the comment:

> Can you reproduce your issue with sample data in a fidle:
> dbfiddle.uk/vRbqFpk_?

The question received 3 answers (their quality or validity is not important).

Image for everyone who cannot view the deleted question: [image]

Today, the user that asked the question, left this comment:

> Congrats, guys! There are no errors in the query I posted. It was a
> trick question to evaluate how the answers would come out. Tks for
> sharing your knowledge!

Since this is the first time I see such a case and although it feels like I should simply raise a flag about this *question* (which should fall under *in need of moderator intervention*), I'm asking if there should be any other/different action about it.

Answer (score 20):

Nothing more is needed than what you have already done.

The question was not reproducible and was closed as such, so the system worked in this case.

If a user makes a habit of wasting contributor time for fun, raise a moderator flag against him, but for a one-off case, I don't think it is needed.